# Change UITableViewCell's height after tableview is shown

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview, and each tableviewcell has a button.

I want to change current cell height when cell's button clicked.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array that holds your selected cells index's

   ```
   var selectedCellIndexs : NSMutableArray = []
   ```
2. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) function add:

   ```
   self.selectedCellIndexs.addObject(indexPath)
   tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
   ```
3. Now in the tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath), all you need to do is check if the cell is part of the selected array and if it is return a different value.

   ```
   if (self.selectedCellIndexs.containsObject(indexPath)) {
       return selectedHeight 
   }
   return notSelectedHeight
   ```
4. Remember to that if you want to deselect a cell you will need to remove the index path from your selectedCellIndexs when the cell is clicked.

NOTE: This is the basic work flow for when the user selects the cell to change the height. A bit more work is needed to get the cell from the button action.

Answer (score 0):

You should store all tableviewcell's height in an `NSMutableArray`.

When user clicks on tableviewcell's button, update `height` in `NSMutableArray`.

After that `reload` your `UITableView`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Globally declare a mutableArray.

```
var buttonPressedIndexPaths : NSMutableArray = []
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` method

```
cell?.button.tag = indexPath.row
cell?.button.addTarget(self, action: "onButtonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

copy paste these methods

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
       if(buttonPressedIndexPaths.containsObject(indexPath))
       {
        return 90;//button pressed cell height
    }
    else
       {
        return 44;//normal
    }
}

func onButtonAction(sender:UIButton)
{
    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)//section may differ based on ur requirement
    if(buttonPressedIndexPaths.containsObject(indexPath))
    {
        buttonPressedIndexPaths.removeObject(indexPath)
    }
    else
    {
        buttonPressedIndexPaths.addObject(indexPath)
    }
    tableView.reloadData();
}
```